# How do I "set CONFIG_DRM_I915=n" to debug suspend/resume?

Tags: suspend, 17.10, hibernate, resume

I'm trying to debug my suspend/resume issues following the instructions on [this blog](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues)

Being a linux newbie, half of this stuff looks like hieroglyphics. Here's one step that I'm trying to get done:

> Disable the kernel graphics driver you're using. On Intel platforms, set CONFIG_DRM_I915=n.

I've googled for about 2 hours on how to do this. Anyone know? Excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CONFIG_DRM_I915`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DRM_I915.html) is a kernel *build* configuration option. To change it you need to rebuild the Linux kernel from source.

There is an easier way to disable the i915 driver though: disable its kernel module via the module "blacklist".

- For a one-off test, edit the kernel command-line to add `i915.blacklist=yes`.

  1. During boot in the Grub menu, select the boot entry for your Ubuntu boot configuration.
  2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it.
  3. Go to the end of the line that starts with `linux`.
  4. Add the above parameter.
  5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot the current configuration.

  For more info see [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](/q/19486/175814)
- For a permanent addition to the blacklist:

  ```sh
  sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-i915.conf > /dev/null <<< 'blacklist i915'
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```

  Then reboot.

  For more info see [How to blacklist kernel modules?](/q/110341/175814)